# Unable to Save a Schema with newly added Field Type?

Tags: content-manager, schema, field-type

We are created New field type on CMS.

we are getting below errors while saving the schema with this new field type.

We are suspecting the save issue is due to this source XML not being updated with the newly added field of type DAMLink with below error

[image]

Code Changes
Below listed components has been added or modified as part of this CC.

[image]

Comment: I didn't think the field types in the Content Manager were extendible in how you're trying to change them. Do you have link to the example or documentation topic on extending these? For "external" links, the extensible approaches I've seen and recommended have been through an External Content Library provider (ECL), Custom URL, or external Multimedia Component. Though given some resources to develop an integration to choose items from a DAM, I'd prefer ECL. :-)

Comment: I'll also add that Schemas are defined by an XSD and the Content Manager will check if a Schema is valid. There's a somewhat related concept of "Web" versus "Complex" Schemas where the Content Manager Explorer can handle and render a GUI for Schemas that fit the "Web" constraints. And the Content Manager could handle even more complicated Schemas, but if it can't save at all then there indeed is likely an issue with the XML/XSD itself.